# Will supplemental heating source shut down my heat pump?

Tags: heating, heat-pump

What happens to the heat pump when a space heater is used as a supplemental source?I have been told it will shut down my heat pump and in very cold weather it could freeze my pipes. My house was built in 1952. I have been told it needs insulation. The return is placed at the rear of the house which stays warm and the front of house is cold.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where the temperature sensor(s)/thermostats are and where the heat sources are. Imagine a single-room setup - using a heater means the heat pump will not work as hard or as often because the sensors and the heater/heat pump are all in one place.

In a real house with a single large heat pump the ducting and heat pump is likely set up to keep the pipes etc from freezing just from heat leakage into the basement. So it warms the house but also keeps the basement/pipework above freezing. Newer ones even have temperature sensors on them to make sure this happens.

Using one heater is probably no big deal, but too many and you are correct: the heaters will run *instead of* the heat pump, the basement will cool down, and things down there freeze.

Trying to fix the front of the house being cold even when the system is "working normally" (ie, not doing what you want) might be as easy as cleaning the ducts, or putting a (partial) shutoff into a duct, or as complex as adding a whole new heat pump to the front of the house. It's the sort of thing that anyone selling ducted heating can proably look at and tell you quickly and easily, but it will take someone looking at your actual house.